# How do I indicate which "oneOf" API response will use?

Tags: jsonschema, json-api

I have an API where the basic response of one key will have an array of identifiers. A user may pass an extra parameter so the array will turn to an array of objects from an array of strings (for actual details rather than having to make a separate call).

```
"children": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "oneOf": [{
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Identifier of child"
    }, {
      "type": "object",
      "description": "Contains details about the child"
    }]
  }
},
```

Is there a way to indicate that the first type comes by a default and the second via a requested param?

Comment: extend the oneOf model with a new property and set it on the server side?

Comment: I don't understand? I am referencing http://json-schema.org/

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish with the distinction. Really that sounds like documentation; maybe elaborate in the `description`s of each `oneOf` subschema.

You could add an additional boolean field at the top level (sibling of `children`) to indicate whether detailed responses are returned and provide a default value for that field. The next step is to couple the value of the boolean to the type of the array items, which I've done using `oneOf`.

I'm suggesting something along the lines of:

```
{                                                                               
  "children": {                                                                 
    "type": "array",                                                            
    "items": {                                                                  
      "oneOf": [                                                                
        {                                                                       
          "type": "string",                                                     
          "description": "Identifier of child",
          "pattern": "^([A-Z0-9]-?){4}$"                                  
        },                                                                      
        {                                                                       
          "type": "object",                                                     
          "description": "Contains details about the child",
          "properties": {
            "age": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          }                    
        }                                                                       
      ]                                                                         
    }                                                                           
  },                                                                            
  "detailed": {                                                                 
    "type": "boolean",                                                          
    "description": "If true, children array contains extra details.",           
    "default": false                                                            
  },                                                                            
  "oneOf": [                                                                    
    {                                                                           
      "detailed": {                                                             
        "enum": [                                                               
          true                                                                  
        ]                                                                       
      },                                                                        
      "children": {                                                             
        "type": "array",                                                        
        "items": {                                                              
          "type": "object"                                                      
        }                                                                       
      }                                                                         
    },                                                                          
    {                                                                           
      "detailed": {                                                             
        "enum": [                                                               
          false                                                                 
        ]                                                                       
      },                                                                        
      "children": {                                                             
        "type": "array",                                                        
        "items": {                                                              
          "type": "string"                                                      
        }                                                                       
      }                                                                         
    }                                                                           
  ]                                                                             
}
```

The second `oneOf` places a further requirement on the response object that when `"detailed": true` the type of items of the "children" array must be "object". This refines the first `oneOf` restriction that describes the schema of objects in the "children" array.

Comment: I see you're suggesting that `detailed` is shown as response (aside from just being a query param going in), but not necessarily actually returned and just used for doc purpose here. I get lost on the need for your extra `oneOf` after `detailed`. It seems you are intending for the first `oneOf` to rely on `$ref`and then later use `definitions` rather than `oneOf`

Comment: You don't share anything between the `oneOf`s; they intentionally overlap, but they are saying different things. I updated my answer to try and clarify.